# Incompatible types using CDate() in Access VBA

Tags: vba, ms-access

I'm calculating with dates in MS Access using VBA. This works fine when I have two dates on the same form (ex 2016-01-21) but not when I first need to modify a string into date form like this: 20160121 -> 2016-01-21.

This is what I'm trying to do:

```
Dim sYear As String, sMonth As String, sDay As String, sDate As String

sYear = Left("20160121", 4)
sMonth = Mid("20160121", 5, 2)
sDay = Mid("20160121", 7, 2)

sDate = sYear & "-" & sMonth & "-" & sDay

MsgBox CDate(sDate)
```

This returns Error 13, Incompatible types.

This works though:

```
MsgBox CDate("2016-01-21")
```

Why doesn't my way work?

Comment: The code above works. My guess is that `"20160121"` is not actually a fixed value, but database field that can contain Null? If that's so, use [the `Nz()` function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa172237%28v=office.11%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

Comment: You're right, it works, but... Instead of "20160121" I have a variable, var, that I get from a textbox. I can user var in the Left() and cDate() works, but when I use it in the Mid() it doesn't... Does it make it any clearer?

Comment: No, not really, unfortunately. Set a breakpoint in your code, step through it line by line, make note of the exact line the error occurs and all the variable values at that point in time. This has to be a simple oversight and not a real issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was because I tested with a false date: 12345678 instead. With a correct date it works fine...

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to decide what to do for invalid input values.

One option is to provide a default date of your choice, today's date or here *1980-01-01*:

```
Public Function ConvertDate(ByVal TextDate As String) As Date

    Dim RealDate    As Date
    Dim NullDate    As Date

    NullDate = #1/1/1980#

    TextDate = Format(TextDate, "@@@@/@@/@@")
    If IsDate(TextDate) Then
        RealDate = CDate(TextDate)
    Else
        RealDate = NullDate
    End If

    ConvertDate = RealDate

End Function
```

Will return:

```
20160121 -> 2016-01-21
20160141 -> 1980-01-01
```

Or you may change the data type of `RealDate` to *Variant* and return *Null* for invalid dates:

```
Public Function ConvertDate(ByVal TextDate As String) As Variant

    Dim RealDate    As Variant
    Dim NullDate    As Variant

    NullDate = Null     

    TextDate = Format(TextDate, "@@@@/@@/@@")
    If IsDate(TextDate) Then
        RealDate = CDate(TextDate)
    Else
        RealDate = NullDate
    End If

    ConvertDate = RealDate

End Function
```

Will return:

```
20160121 -> 2016-01-21
20160141 -> Null
```