# Interval between two dates in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

Start time `"08:58"`, end time `"17:37"`. Expected result is 8.39 meaning elapsed time of 8 hours and 39 minutes. I tried this:

```
Function UDF_datediff(d1 As Date, d2 As Date) As Double
    Dim hours As Integer
    Dim minutes As Integer

    hours = DateDiff("h", d1, d2)
    minutes = (DateDiff("n", d1, d2) Mod 60)

    UDF_datediff = hours + minutes / 100
End Function
```

But it calculates wrong results for hours. Surprisingly!
Would you share any suggestion to calculate expected results?

Comment: Have you searched on here? This has been asked before

Comment: @SolarMike please suggest phrase to google. I tried `site:stackoverflow.com interval between to dates vba` and other variations or please post link to duplicate.

Comment: Well, I searched for "vba calculate dates" and found this one as a possible relevant example, you should think about keywords... https://stackoverflow.com/q/36302022/4961700

Comment: `t = DateDiff("n", d1, d2) / 60:
h = Int(t):
m = (t - h) * 60`

Comment: `hours = DateDiff("h", d1, d2)`, which (within the same day) is equivalent to `hours = Hour(d2) - Hour(d1)`, a.k.a. `hours = 17 - 8`

Comment: 8:39  *24 = 8.65

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
Sub test()
    Dim d1 As Date, d2 As Date
    Dim m As Double

    d1 = TimeValue("08:58")
    d2 = TimeValue("17:37")
    m = UDF_datediff(d1, d2)
    MsgBox m
    MsgBox Format(m / 24, "hh:mm")
End Sub
```

UDF

```
Function UDF_datediff(d1 As Date, d2 As Date) As Double

    UDF_datediff = (d2 - d1) * 24
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Sub Test()
    Dim minutes As Long
    Dim d1 As Date, d2 As Date
    d1 = "2018-01-01 08:58:00"
    d2 = "2018-01-01 17:37:00"
    minutes = DateDiff("n", d1, d2)
    ' Will print 8.39
    MsgBox Int(minutes / 60) & "." & minutes Mod 60
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

```vb
Function UDF_datediff(d1 As Date, d2 As Date) As Double
    Dim difference AS Double
    difference = d2 - d1
    UDF_datediff = Sgn(difference) * CDbl(Format(difference , "hh.mm"))
End Function
```

In your example, d2 - d1 is a DateTime of `1899-12-30 08:37:00` - Format this as Hours (2 digits), decimal point, Minutes (2 digits), then convert to a double and correct the sign.

Comment: Love this answer for simplicity. Thank you all, for presenting different approaches.

Comment: @Chronocidal:  So what does the number 8.37 mean to a random observer? Is it not 8+37/100, right? Of course you do not mean this; yet, It's a number! 08:37 is OK, 8:37 is OK as well, 8.37 is... not quite, and you need to explain it to whoever is not familiar with this "notation".  Dy.Lee's comment above (with 8.65) makes sense to me, not this one. Besides, what happens to, say, days if the date/time difference is large? Your "method" removes any whole days from the answer.

Comment: @Gene The number "8.37" means "8 hours and 37 minutes" in the format that the OP asked for.  There **are** countries that format their time that way, e.g. [Finland](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Date_and_time_notation_in_Finland) or [Poland](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Date_and_time_notation_in_Poland) (OP's personal website in their profile is Polish). And, if the input is a pair of 24-hour times, *without a day* (again, as specified by OP), then a difference greater than 24 hours is impossible.  If dates are included, just use `Format(difference , "[HH].mm")` to show hours over 23

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old thread but I found it helpful. Here is how I implemented it.

```
    Public Function GetInterval(dStartDate As Date, dEndDate As Date, _
                                Optional sDaysText As String = " days") As String
    Dim lSeconds As Long
        ' Note: To get standard day formatting, pass sDaysText argument as an empty string.
        lSeconds = DateDiff("s", dStartDate, dEndDate)
        GetInterval = GetIntervalText(lSeconds, sDaysText)
    End Function
    
    Private Function GetIntervalText(ByVal lSeconds As Long, _
                                     Optional sDaysText As String = vbNullString) As String
    Dim lDays As Long, lHours As Long, lMinutes As Long
    Dim sInterval As String
    Dim sDays As String, sHours As String, sMinutes As String, sSeconds As String
        ' Days
        lDays = IIf(lSeconds >= 86400, lSeconds \ 86400, 0)
        sDays = IIf(lDays = 0, vbNullString, _
                IIf(sDaysText = vbNullString, Format(lDays, "00:"), lDays & sDaysText))
        If sDays <> vbNullString Then
            If sDaysText <> vbNullString Then
                If lDays = 1 Then
                    ' Strip plural for 1.
                    If StrComp(Right$(sDays, 1), "s", vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
                        If Right$(sDays, 3) = "ies" Then
                            sDays = Left$(sDays, Len(sDays) - 3) & "y"
                        ElseIf Right$(sDays, 3) = "IES" Then
                            sDays = Left$(sDays, Len(sDays) - 3) & "Y"
                        ElseIf StrComp(Right$(sDays, 3), "ies", vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
                            sDays = Left$(sDays, Len(sDays) - 3) & "y"
                        Else
                            sDays = Left$(sDays, Len(sDays) - 1)
                        End If
                    End If
                End If
                sDays = sDays & ", "
            End If
        End If
        lSeconds = lSeconds - (lDays * 86400)
        ' Hours
        lHours = IIf(lSeconds >= 3600, lSeconds \ 3600, 0)
        sHours = Format(lHours, "00:")
        lSeconds = lSeconds - (lHours * 3600)
        ' Minutes
        lMinutes = IIf(lSeconds >= 60, lSeconds \ 60, 0)
        lSeconds = lSeconds - (lMinutes * 60)
        sMinutes = Format(lMinutes, "00:")
        ' Seconds
        sSeconds = Format(lSeconds, "00")
        
        sInterval = sDays & sHours & sMinutes & sSeconds
        Do While Left$(sInterval, 3) = "00:"
            sInterval = Mid$(sInterval, 4, 1000)
        Loop
        ' Minimum 0:00
        If InStr(sInterval, ":") = 0 Then
            sInterval = "0:" & sInterval
        End If
        If Left$(sInterval, 1) = 0 Then
            If IsNumeric(Mid$(sInterval, 2, 1)) Then
                sInterval = Mid$(sInterval, 2, 1000)
            End If
        End If
        
        GetIntervalText = sInterval
    End Function
    
    Private Sub TestInterval()
    Dim lSeconds As Long, lResult As Long
    Dim sText As String, sDaysText As String
        lResult = MsgBox("Please select days formatting. " & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
                          "Click Yes to format as x days, hh:mm:ss or " & vbNewLine & _
                          "Click No to format as dd:hh:mm:ss.", & _
                          vbYesNoCancel Or vbQuestion, "Confirm Days Formatting")
        If lResult = vbYes Then
            sDaysText = " days"
        ElseIf lResult = vbNo Then
            sDaysText = vbNullString
        Else
            Exit Sub
        End If
        
        ' Skip all but days.
        If False Then
            ' Seconds
            lSeconds = 1
            sText = GetIntervalText(lSeconds): Debug.Print lSeconds, sText
            lSeconds = 60 - 1
            ' Minutes
            sText = GetIntervalText(lSeconds): Debug.Print lSeconds, sText
            lSeconds = 60
            sText = GetIntervalText(lSeconds): Debug.Print lSeconds, sText
            lSeconds = 60 + 1
            sText = GetIntervalText(lSeconds): Debug.Print lSeconds, sText
            lSeconds = 3600 - 1
            sText = GetIntervalText(lSeconds): Debug.Print lSeconds, sText
            ' Hours
            lSeconds = 3600
            sText = GetIntervalText(lSeconds): Debug.Print lSeconds, sText
            lSeconds = 3601
            sText = GetIntervalText(lSeconds): Debug.Print lSeconds, sText
            lSeconds = 3661
            sText = GetIntervalText(lSeconds): Debug.Print lSeconds, sText
            lSeconds = 86400 - 1
            sText = GetIntervalText(lSeconds): Debug.Print lSeconds, sText
        End If
        ' Days
        lSeconds = 86400
        sText = GetIntervalText(lSeconds, sDaysText): Debug.Print lSeconds, sText
        lSeconds = 86400 + 1
        sText = GetIntervalText(lSeconds, sDaysText): Debug.Print lSeconds, sText
        lSeconds = 86400 + 60
        sText = GetIntervalText(lSeconds, sDaysText): Debug.Print lSeconds, sText
        lSeconds = 86400 + 61
        sText = GetIntervalText(lSeconds, sDaysText): Debug.Print lSeconds, sText
        lSeconds = 86400 + 3600
        sText = GetIntervalText(lSeconds, sDaysText): Debug.Print lSeconds, sText
        lSeconds = 86400 + 3600 + 1
        sText = GetIntervalText(lSeconds, sDaysText): Debug.Print lSeconds, sText
        lSeconds = 86400 + 3600 + 61
        sText = GetIntervalText(lSeconds, sDaysText): Debug.Print lSeconds, sText
        lSeconds = (86400 * 3) + 75184
        sText = GetIntervalText(lSeconds, sDaysText): Debug.Print lSeconds, sText
    End Sub
```

Comment: Appreciate your effort though I am not able to check it as Excel became an obsolete tech for me.

Answer (score 0):

`DateDiff` is actually not quite needed. You may use a simple "minus" to see what's going on:

```
Sub TestMe() 

    With Worksheets(1)
        Dim d1 As Date: d1 = 0.373611111111111 '08:58:00
        Dim d2 As Date: d2 = 0.734027777777778 '17:37:00
    End With
    Debug.Print UdfDatediff(d1, d2)            '08:39:00

End Sub

Function UdfDatediff(d1 As Date, d2 As Date) As Date

    UdfDatediff = Abs(d1 - d2)

End Function
```

The date in VBA is presented as a double number. Thus, if you write 0.373611111111111 and format it to in Date in VBA you would get:

```
?CDate(0.373611111111111)
08:58:00
```

The double values above are obtained through writing the following in the *Immediate Window* <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>:

```
?CDbl(TimeSerial(8,58,0))
 0,373611111111111
```

In Excel, the date is also presented as a double number, but for the first two months of the year **1900** it is a bit deviating from the date in VBA (See the question of [BillG here](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2006/06/16/my-first-billg-review/)).

Comment: Well, you should also post how to obtain such value as `0.3736111`. We may know it, but without this, the answer is incomplete IMO.

Comment: @MichałTurczyn - true, I have posted a way to get it.

Answer (score -1):

alternatively - given that times are stored as decimal fractions of a day

```
 Function UDF_datediff(d1 As Date, d2 As Date) As Double
    d2 = d2-int(d2) 'remove date portion
    d1= d1 - int(d1)
    UDF_datediff = (d2-d1)*24
  End Function
```

Comment: Returns 8.65 instead 8.39.